# Trace Loop Python, Why the Output is 90?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

I am tracing the loops in the code. Can anyone help me trace through the code and help me understand why the output is 90?

```
m = 4
n = 5
x = 0
for i in range(1,m):
       x = x + i + 10            //x inside i loop
       for j in range(1,n):
            x = x + i + j        //x inside j loop
print(x)
```

Comment: I don't see where you've made any attempt to trace the program.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
We expect you to try solving the problem on your own, and present those results when you ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want every progress of the loop.

Code:

```
m = 4
n = 5
x = 0
for i in range(1,m):
    print("Outer Loop: {}+{}+10".format(x, i))
    x = x + i + 10
    print("Outer Sum x=",x)
    for j in range(1,n):
        print("\tInner Loop: {}+{}+{}".format(x, i, j))
        x = x + i + j
        print("\tInner Sum =", x)
print("Total =",x)
```

Output:

```
Outer Loop: 0+1+10
Outer Sum x= 11
    Inner Loop: 11+1+1
    Inner Sum = 13
    Inner Loop: 13+1+2
    Inner Sum = 16
    Inner Loop: 16+1+3
    Inner Sum = 20
    Inner Loop: 20+1+4
    Inner Sum = 25
Outer Loop: 25+2+10
Outer Sum x= 37
    Inner Loop: 37+2+1
    Inner Sum = 40
    Inner Loop: 40+2+2
    Inner Sum = 44
    Inner Loop: 44+2+3
    Inner Sum = 49
    Inner Loop: 49+2+4
    Inner Sum = 55
Outer Loop: 55+3+10
Outer Sum x= 68
    Inner Loop: 68+3+1
    Inner Sum = 72
    Inner Loop: 72+3+2
    Inner Sum = 77
    Inner Loop: 77+3+3
    Inner Sum = 83
    Inner Loop: 83+3+4
    Inner Sum = 90
Total = 90
```

Answer (score 1):

Tracing a loop is easy, just add print statements inside (here first i is used to iterate over 1 to 4 and then i+10 is added to x and then again j is iterated 1 to 5 and add i+j to x)

```
m = 4
n = 5
x = 0
for i in range(1,m):
       x = x + i + 10
       print(x)
       
       for j in range(1,n):
            x = x + i + j
            print(x, end = " ")
       print()
       print()

print(x)
```

After running the following code you will see the following output

```
11                                                                                                                                                                                                     
13 16 20 25                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                       
37                                                                                                                                                                                                     
40 44 49 55                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                       
68                                                                                                                                                                                                     
72 77 83 90                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                       
90
```

Comment: I mean how the python work in logical formulas, like math